# Method of characteristic curves

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, characteristics

I'm trying to understand the method of characteristic curves, in that purpose I have these two exercises, but i think somwhere i get totaly wrong with this

> I need to allocate areas of a constant type of a second-order equation with two independent variables on the plane. Bring it to the canonical form in the specified area 
> $x\cdot u_{xx} + y\cdot u_{yy} = 0, x<0, y<0$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{u_x}{u_y}, \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = u_{xx}u_y-2u_x u_{xy} +u_{yy}u_x$
$x u_{xx}+yu_{yy}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{y}{x}$
Let's solve the differential equation defining the characteristic curves 
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{y}{x} \Rightarrow y =c_1 x\cdot cos( ln(-x))+c_2 x \cdot sin( ln(-x))$ 
We need characteristic curves passing through x<0, y<0. Substitute the boundary conditions $y(0)=c_1=0, y(-1)=0=c_1 cos(ln(-1))$ 
So $c_1=0$ and $ln(-1)=\pi i$ 
hence solution is $y=\pm i x$ 
Substitute the resulting solution into the initial equation 
$xu_{xx}+yu_{yy}=xu_{xx}-(\pm i)^2 u =0$ 
$v=x^{1/2} u$ 
$v_{xx}=\frac{(\pm i)^2}{x} v=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDE
$$
xu_{xx}+yu_{yy}=0 \tag{1}
$$
is elliptic in the region $x<0$, $y<0$. Hence, to write it in canonical form, we need to find a change of variables $(x,y)\mapsto(\xi,\eta)$ such that$^{(*)}$
$$
w_{\xi\xi}+w_{\eta\eta}+aw_{\xi}+bw_{\eta}+cw=d, \tag{2}
$$
where $w(\xi,\eta)=u(x,y)$ and $a,b,c$ and $d$ are functions of $\xi$ and $\eta$.

Let's make the simplifying assumption that $\xi=\xi(x)$ and $\eta=\eta(y)$; then, using the chain rule, we find
$$
u_{xx}=\xi_x^2w_{\xi\xi}+\xi_{xx}w_{\xi}, \qquad
u_{yy}=\eta_y^2w_{\eta\eta}+\eta_{yy}w_{\eta}, \tag{3}
$$
so that $(1)$ becomes
$$
x(\xi_x^2w_{\xi\xi}+\xi_{xx}w_{\xi})+y(\eta_y^2w_{\eta\eta}+\eta_{yy}w_{\eta})=0. \tag{4}
$$
To put $(4)$ in the form $(2)$, we multiply it by $-1$ and choose $\xi$ and $\eta$ such that$^{(\dagger)}$ $\xi_x^2=-\frac{1}{x}$ and $\eta_y^2=-\frac{1}{y}$, or $(\xi,\eta)=(2(-x)^{1/2},2(-y)^{1/2})$; then $(4)$ becomes
$$
w_{\xi\xi}+w_{\eta\eta}-\frac{1}{\xi}w_{\xi}-\frac{1}{\eta}w_{\eta}=0. \tag{5}
$$

---

$^{(*)}$See, for instance, [Classification of Second Order Linear PDE's and Reduction to Canonical Form](https://faculty.uml.edu/spennell/Teaching/PDE/classification.pdf#:%7E:text=second%20order%20linear%20pde%20can%20be%20reduced%20to,%CE%BE%20%3D%20%CE%BE%28x%2C%20y%29%2C%20%CE%B7%20%3D%20%CE%B7%28x%2C%20y%29.), by Steve Pennell.

$^{(\dagger)}$Recall that $x<0$, $y<0$.